# display open ports grouped by process

Tags: bash, shell

given a `netstat` output, how can i display the selected open ports grouped by process?

what i got so far:

```
:~# netstat -tnlp | awk '/25|80|443|465|636|993/ {proc=split($7,pr,"/"); port=split($4,po,":"); print pr[2], po[port]}' 

haproxy 636
haproxy 993
haproxy 993
haproxy 465
haproxy 465
exim4 25
apache2 80
exim4 25
apache2 443
```

desired output (in one line):

```
apache2 (80 443), exim4 (25), haproxy (465 636 993)
```

please note:

- i have duplicated lines because they listen on different IPs, but i only need one (`sort -u` is ok)
- if possible, id like to sort by process and then by port

the main goal is to have this single line displayed to the user on ssh logon, using `motd` (i got this part covered)

Answer (score 1):

```
netstat -tnlp|awk '/25|80|443|465|636|993/ {proc=split($7,pr,"/"); port=split($4,po,":"); print pr[2], po[port]}'|sort|uniq|awk '{a[$1]=a[$1](" "$2" "$3)}END{for (i in a) printf "%s (%s),",i,a[i]}'
```

try this, Later addition

```
sort|uniq|awk '{a[$1]=a[$1](" "$2" "$3)}END{for (i in a) printf "%s (%s),",i,a[i]}'
```

Comment: +1 for your efforts. very good answer, but the ports are not ordered and the last char in the line is a comma. also, would it be possible to reduce piping through 2 awk into just 1?

Comment: ```netstat -tnlp|awk '/25|80|443|465|636|993/ {proc=split($7,pr,"/"); port=split($4,po,":"); print pr[2], po[port]}'|uniq|sort -nk2|awk '{a[$1]=a[$1](" "$2" "$3)}END{for (i in a) printf "%s (%s),",i,a[i]}'|sed 's/.$//' ```  ,this ordered ,and i can't through 1 awk, Can only help here